# How can I add a simple link to a variable using openlayers / cloudmade?

Tags: javascript, layer, cloudmade

Here's the code I've got;

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://tile.cloudmade.com/wml/latest/web-maps-lite.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    var cloudmade = new CM.Tiles.CloudMade.Web({key: '1b67988f99f947e3bd06fbcf924aeda1', styleId:19933});
    var map = new CM.Map('mapa', cloudmade);
    map.setCenter(new CM.LatLng(-24.900, -83.000), 4);

    var bottomRight = new CM.ControlPosition(CM.BOTTOM_RIGHT, new CM.Size(50, 20));
    map.addControl(new CM.SmallMapControl(), bottomRight);

    var CloudMadeIcon = new CM.Icon();
    CloudMadeIcon.image = "http://remidia.com.br/autopauta/wp-content/uploads/2010/marcador.gif";
    CloudMadeIcon.iconSize = new CM.Size(10, 10);


    var areiaGrande = new CM.LatLng(-9.253,-41.108);
    var areiaMarker = new CM.Marker (areiaGrande, {
    title: "Areia Grande (Casa Nova/BA)",
    icon: CloudMadeIcon, clickable:true, 

    });



    map.addOverlay(areiaMarker);




   </script>
```

How can I add a link (ex: href "http://www.areia.com") to the "areiaMarker" variable?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to use title as a link in CloudMade Web Maps API, but you can use InfoWindow instead.

Here is an example: http://developers.cloudmade.com/projects/web-maps-api/examples/info-window